# metodo clase hija visible desde la superclase

Tags: java, herencia

Tengo una superclase(Calzado) y clases hijas(Zapato-Zapatilla).  Tengo un metodo getIva() en la clase Zapatilla y necesito recuperar este valor Iva desde la superclase.

El manejo con el super esta resuelto, y no identifico com orecuperar el dato.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ejecutora {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    Principal p = new Principal();
    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opc = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("1 - AGREGA UN CALZADO" );
        System.out.println("2 - LISTA ARTICULOS ");
        System.out.println("3 - LISTA PRECIOS CON IVA");
        System.out.println("4 - LISTAR COLORES");
        opc = e.nextInt();
        switch ( opc ) {
        case 1: {
            p.agregaCalzado();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            p.listaArticulos();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            p.listarPrecio();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            p.listarColores();
            break;
        }
        }
    } while ( opc != 0);
    }
    } 

import java.util.*;
public class Principal {
private ArrayList<Calzado>calzados;

public Principal(){
    calzados = new ArrayList<Calzado>();
}

public void agregaCalzado() {
    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    e.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    System.out.println("INGRESE EL CODIGO DEL CALZADO");
    int codi = e.nextInt();
    Calzado c = this.buscaCalzado(codi);
    if ( c != null ) {
        System.out.println("EL CALZADO YA FUE CARGADO");
    }
    else {
        int opc = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("1- ZAPATILLA  | 2 - ZAPATO ");
            opc = e.nextInt();
        } while ( opc != 1 && opc != 2);

        System.out.println("INGRESE EL DETALLE DEL CALZADO");
        String detalle = e.next();
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL TALLE DEL CALZADO");
        float tall = e.nextFloat() ;
        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL CALZADO");
        float prec = e.nextFloat();
        Calzado nuevo;
        if ( opc == 1 ) {
            System.out.println("INGRESE EL IVA");
            float iva = e.nextFloat();
            nuevo = new Zapatilla ( codi, detalle, tall, prec, iva );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("INGRESE LA COMISION");
            float comi = e.nextFloat();
            nuevo = new Zapato ( codi, detalle, tall, prec, comi );
        }
        calzados.add(nuevo);
    }
}

public void listarColores() {
    for ( Calzado ca: calzados) {
        System.out.println("EL DETALLE ES: " + ca.getDetalle());
    }
}

public void listaValores() {
    for ( Calzado c: calzados ) {
        System.out.println("DETALLE: " + c.getDetalle() + "PRECIO: " + c.getPrecio() + "IVA: " );
    }
}

public void listarPrecio() {
    float sumaPrecio = 0;
    for (Calzado ca: calzados) {
        sumaPrecio = sumaPrecio + ca.darPrecio();
        System.out.println("LOS PRECIO SON: " + ca.darPrecio() + "CODIGO: " + ca.getCodigo());
    }
    System.out.println("LA SUMA ES DE PRECIO ES: " + sumaPrecio);
}

public void listaArticulos() {
    for ( Calzado c: calzados ) {
        System.out.println("codigo: " + c.getCodigo() + " detalle: " + c.getDetalle());
    }
}

public Calzado buscaCalzado(int c) {
    int a = 0;
    while ( a < calzados.size() && !( calzados.get(a).sosCodigo(c)))
        a ++;
    if ( a < calzados.size())
        return calzados.get(a);
    else 
        return null;
}
}


public abstract class Calzado {
private int codigo;
private String detalle;
private float talle;
private float precio;

public Calzado ( int cod, String det, float tal, float pre ) {
    codigo = cod;
    detalle = det;
    talle = tal;
    precio = pre;
}


public boolean sosCodigo(int a) {
    return (codigo == a);
}

public float darPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public String getDetalle() {
    return detalle;
}

public float getTalle() {
    return talle;
}

public float getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
}

public class Zapatilla extends Calzado {
private float iva;

public Zapatilla ( int cod, String col, float tal, float pre, float i ) {
    super ( cod, col, tal, pre );
    iva = i;
}

public float darPrecio() {
    float res = 0;
    res = ( iva * 5 + super.darPrecio());
    return res;
}

public float getIva() {
    return iva;
}
}


public class Zapato extends Calzado {
private float comision;

public Zapato ( int cod, String col, float tal, float pre, float comis ) {
    super (cod, col, tal, pre);
    comision = comis;
}

public float darComision() {
    return comision;
}

public float darPrecio() {
    float cos = 0;
    cos = ( comision * 10 + super.darPrecio());
    return cos;
}
}
```

Comment: Me temo que te va a ser imposible sin hacer Cast a la clase hija pues la padre nunca va a conocer datos de las hijas.

Comment: Si todos los "Calzados" van a tener "iva" y lo vas a necesitar desde el padre, debería ser un método del padre, y los hijos lo heredarán, de este modo podrás llamarlo desde el padre como pretendes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 formas en la que puedes hacerlo.

Declarando el metodo en la clase base y así podrás acceder al valor aun cuando en la declaracion sea del tipo del padre:

```
public abstract class Padre {
 public abstract int getIva();
}

public class Hija extends Padre {
  @Override
  public int getIva(){ return 44; }
}

Padre padre = new Hija();
System.out.println(padre.getIva().toString()); // 44
```

O creas una interfaz que contiene el metodo `getIva()` y lo implementas en las clases que requieren ese método. Luego tendrás que preguntar si la instancia es del tipo de la interfaz para luego castear y obtener el valor:

```
public interface IIvaInterface{
    int getIva();
}
public abstract class Padre {
    //...
}

public class Hija extends Padre implements IIvaInterface {
    @Override
    public int getIva(){ return 44; }
}

Padre padre = new Hija();
int iva = 0;
if(padre instanceof IIvaInterface)
{
  iva = ((IIvaInterface)padre).getIva();
}

System.out.println(iva.toString()); // 44
```